# Angular JS $http promise executes twice

Tags: angularjs, json, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to get data from json with AngularJS and I have a problem with it. Could You tell me why does my very simple angularJS code fragment logs data twice?

```
   $http.get("../news/news.json").then(function(res){
      console.log(res.data);
   });
```

Comment: Where do you call this? Probably you are calling it twice!

Comment: It might be the things that you are loading controller from route & you also has `ng-controller` on page where, which is instantiating controller twice & your method is also getting called twice

Answer (score 1):

Just like @PankajParkar said. I was instatinating controller twice. Once in body and once from route. Separated it to another controller and now it works fine. Tanks again.